# Does the FFmpeg snapshot have a PGP signature?

Tags: ffmpeg

I downloaded the [development branch snapshot of FFmpeg's source code](https://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2) from [Download FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html).

I want to verify it for authenticity but can't find its PGP signature. Does it have one? If so, where is it?

I tried https://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2.asc but got 404 not found.

Comment: Looking at the releases folder itself the snapshot does not appear to be signed, but all the proper releases do: https://ffmpeg.org/releases/